# Deactivate Date Relationship within Measure

Tags: excel, pivot, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am struggling a bit with a pretty simple measure at the moment.
How can I deactivate a relationship between two tables?
I have a fact table, that shows me all values for each item per date:
Item - Value - Date - State - Type

This table is linked to the calendar table.
In the end, I have pivot table that sums up the values per week.
Now I need an additional column in this pivot table that shows me the total value for all items with a etate of "50", regardless of the date.
I already have tried something like this:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM([Value]);ALL(Calendar);FILTER(tbl;tbl[State]=50))
```

This is not working.

How would you manage that?

Comment: I think the problem is the row context applied by the table visual. Read more about row context and filter context here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-and-filter-context-in-dax/  The `ALLSELECTED` function might help you here, but I would need to know more about your data model.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ALL(Calendar)` part of the formula only impacts the SUM part, it doesn't change any of the other Filters in the CALCULATE, ie `FILTER(tbl;tbl[State]=50)` is still impacted by the particular Week Ending value for that row in your pivot table.

So to fix you can just shorten the `FILTER(tbl;tbl[State]=50)` to be `tbl[State]=50`